# файл становиться больше

Tags: php, gd

данный фрагмент кода уменьшает расширение изображения, но я сильно удивился увидев что вес новых картинок больше чем их оригинал с более высоки расширением, я так понимаю исходные изображения очень хорошо сжаты, но как средствами php сжать их так же хорошо после того как разрешения уменьшено. Возможно ли это??

```js
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
  if ($file['size'] < 2000000) {
    $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
    $temp = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    $percent = 0.5;
    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = $temp;
    $width = $width_orig * $percent;
    $height = $height_orig * $percent;
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imageAlphaBlending($canvas, false);
    imageSaveAlpha($canvas, true);
    if ($image_name != "") {
      $razr = array();
      $razr = explode(".", $image_name);
      $file_extension = end($razr);
      $file_extension = mb_strToLower($file_extension);
    }

    function create_newImage($extension, $url) {
      if ($extension == "jpg") {
        return imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
      }
      if ($extension == "png") {
        return ImageCreateFromPNG($url);
      }
      if ($extension == "gif") {
        return imagecreatefromgif($url);
      }
      return (false);
    }
    $new_image = create_newImage($file_extension, $tmp_name); //
    if ($new_image !== false) {
      imagecopyresampled($canvas, $new_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
      imagepng($canvas, $tmp_name, 0);
      imagedestroy($canvas);
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload.$image_name)) {
      $files = realpath($upload.$image_name);
      $answer = "фаил загружен";
    } else {
      $error = true;
    }
  } else {
    $answer = "фаил слишком большой";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последовательные компрессия и декомпрессия JPEG, даже с хорошим параметром качества, например, 0.95, добавляют небольшой шум, потому что это сжатие с потерями. Алгоритм LZ77, используемый в PNG, ничего не знает про смысл JPEG и сжимает распакованные данные JPEG просто как бинарную строку, пытаясь найти в ней некоторую несложную логику. Логику в графическом шуме, не зная его природы, искать бесполезно, потому результат действий

1. Компрессия JPEG
2. Декомпрессия JPEG
3. Любые операции
4. Компрессия PNG

может оказаться и показаться парадоксальным.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но для новичка то есть для меня, не очень понятен смысл написанного) судя из ваших слов, я так понял, обратно сжать файл так же качественно php не может(это если сказать простыми словами), если вы в курсе ответьте пожалуйста как вообще можно, реализовать это(картинка попала на сервер, я создал такую же но с нужным мне расширением то есть с меньшим расширением,она стала весить больше, но ведь я уменьшал расширения, для того что бы уменьшить её вес, получается данная операция потеряла смысл,ТАК есть ли вообще какой способ её уменьшить???уменьшить в весе)

Comment: Вы уменьшенную картинку сохраняете в формате PNG. Сохраняйте в формате JPEG. Кстати, для уменьшения средствами GD нужно сперва распаковать изображение в растр в памяти. Вот тут PHP-скрипт может и упасть, если загружается здоровенная фотка с нормального девайса. Для уменьшения с минимальным использованием памяти можно использовать прогу `cjpeg` из `libjpeg`, однако, для этого нужно создавать отдельный процесс. Может, какой модуль для этого уже к PHP прикрутили, тут я не в курсе.

Comment: но почему вы пишите что я сохраняю картинку в png, ведь  function create_newImage()  у меня создает картинку именно с таким расширением с каким каким она пришла если пришла в jpeg то и создается jpeg, или я что то не так понял???

Comment: Потому что `imagepng($canvas, $tmp_name, 0);` И да... Вы же картинку без сжатия вообще сохраняете! Третий параметр. Замените 0 на 9.